# How to calculate angular momentum per second for a photon beam?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, photons

Given a photon polarization state $$|\phi\rangle = \frac{3}{5}|x\rangle + \frac{4i}{5}|y\rangle,$$ a beam of photons transmit $N$ photons per second in such a state. An L-polarized photon has an angular momentum $\hbar$ along its direction of motion, and an R-polarized photon has an angular momentum of the same magnitude but opposite to direction of motion. If the beam described by the particular polarization state $|\phi\rangle$ above is totally absorbed by a surface, what angular momentum is added to the surface per second on the average?

Comment: Recall that the average angular momentum carried by a photon in the state $|\phi\rangle$ is $\langle\phi|\vec{L}|\phi\rangle$ where $\vec{L}$ are the angular momentum operators. You'll need to know the matrix elements $\langle x|L_x|y\rangle$ etc. for each combination of states and each $L_i$.